# Filter tags in LogCat (in Android Eclipse Plug-In)

Tags: android, logging, adb, logcat, ddms

There is a TextField "Filter" below the LogCat output. However, it seems to filter only the Message-column. Id like to filter Tags also. Because there are my class names.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I am not able to test the given answer(s) anymore, since I stopped developing Android Apps. Please suggest if I should mark an answer done, if you have tested it and matches the requirements of my question.

Answer (score 33):

There's a button that looks like a green + in the upper right of the log cat window, if you mouse over it says "Create Filter" in the popup from that you can filter by log tag. It creates a new tab in log cat with the filter name you specified. Then all of the output of that tag will go to that tab and not the "Log" tab.

Comment: Can't use wildcards like "com.mynamespace.*" ;( But thanks for showing me that function ;)

Comment: I'd really like to be able to use wildcards in here too.

Answer (score 20):

In Eclipse, if I would like to exclude those annoying Choreographer messages,I write this filter in the logcat filter TextField : `tag:^(?!Choreographer).*$` and it excludes all messages which tag starts with the text `Choreographer`

If you want multiple exclusions : `tag:^(?!Choreographer|dalvikvm-heap|Trace).*$`

Answer (score 13):

The `Log tag` field accepts Java regular expressions, so try this:

```
^TAG_A$|^TAG_B$
```

which matches exactly those tags. You can go crazy with complicated regular expressions, if that's your idea of fun.

Comment: Woah great, I never noticed that. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: This seems to be working only in ADT, since if I use it programatically (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat [<option>] ... [<filter-spec>] ...")), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but still relevant, and didn't see this answer among the answers here.

To filter by multiple columns in logcat textfield, simply use a `space` between regular expressions, and the column title in lower case followed by `:` to assign the regex to that column instead of the default "`text:"`

for example:

```
tag:wif text:event
```

a space '' is used as an *AND* argument.
a single '`|`' without space is an *OR*.

Regarding one of the comments I've seen here - There is no realy need for a wildcard, since it is automatically applied before and after the filter text.
If you don't want wildcard, you can use regular expression syntax to restrict the string. 
for example: `^starswith` or `fullword$`

**TIP:** if you want to match a space character or a tab in your output, just type in: `\s` at the desired place.

Comment: thanks for the tip with the whitespace \s that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

A sample from the [ADB manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html):

> adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S

The `*:S` is vital as this would suppress other tags different than the ones specified by us.

Unfortunately, one can't use wildcards in the names, i.e.:

> adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp*:D *:S

wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

When filtering, you must use no whitespace after 'tag:' and all is case sensitive. For example:

```
tag:MIRKO
```

and not

```
TAG: mirko
```

Answer (score 3):

Run logcat in a shell and pipe it through grep.

There's probably even a way to do execute this from an eclipse window that would capture the output.

Comment: Could you provide the commands how to pipe it in the shell? Sorry, I grew up with OS using GUI and have no clue on those things...

Comment: adb logcat | grep someNameOfInterest    you can also use the -i flag to make it case insensitive.  Oh, and you have to _have_ grep, ie, be on linux or unix or cygwin or msys or have a grep executable for your OS.

Answer (score 1):

this should be the same across all platforms, but I'm specifically doing this on Mac Snow leopard, helios....

with the latest eclipse and android plugin, go to window -> show view -> android -> logcat

then in the upper right corner of the view there are filter buttons : "V" "D" "I" "W" "E" then a + edit and -

click on the + and type in your tag, or pid

enjoy filtered logCat

Answer (score 1):

In LogCat's search textbox, you will see the hint text "Search for messages, Accepts Java regexes, Prefix with pid:, app:, tag: or text: to limit scope."

So just type in tag:YOUR_TAG_NAME