# Developing in Eclipse for Android using Phonegap. 'Untagging Socket' error=-13

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

So I have developed iphone/ipad apps before using Xcode and Phonegap/Cordova for a while now, submitted a few to the app store and they were accepted. So I have decided to convert one from ios to android. Thinking that apart from a few changes from ObjectiveC to JAVA, all the Phonegap stuff would work.

A lot of it does, but there is a few bugs, as you would expect. But one thing that is worrying me is that my output window in Eclipse is constantly being spammed with error messages, even when my development device is idle.

The main error is:

```
Untagging socket (number) failed errno=-13
```

Also errors saying 'tagging' a socket has also failed, with the same error message, I am new to Eclipse and JAVA. And have no idea what this means.

I have Googled the hell out of it with little success, apart from something about paths, but I have checked them all and they seem to be correct.

Has anyone seen this before, or have any idea what might be going on? Or where I should look to try and figure out why this error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter and then you will only see the info from your app.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4044174/41679

Comment: thank you, led me to the right answer and you also helped me with the screenshot plugin yesterday by random coincidence :p