# Fix "scroll up" bug in Eclipse logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I was wondering if you had a way to fix the scrolling glitch with Logcat on Eclipse. Whenever I try to scroll up, the screen moves up for a sec and then goes back to the bottom.

It is really annoying and I can't get to some of my errors because of it.

Comment: Toggle the down arrow in the upper-right corner.

Comment: Should be a little arrow icon on the right. Click that, it should scroll lock then. AFAIK, the new ADT messed this up though and you just scroll up to lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Scroll Lock button.

[image: Scroll Lock button]

Also, consider using the corresponding [LogCat filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044132/filter-tags-in-logcat-in-android-eclipse-plug-in) in order to only display the messages you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this as a error. Unselecting the scroll lock button will not work 99% of the time. As soon as you try to scroll the window (with mouse wheel or clicking the scroll bar up/down arrows) the scroll lock, turns back on.

Solution:

I've found a workaround, after unselecting the scroll lock, then click on a message and then press the page up key on your keyboard once and this will release the lock completely. You can now scroll with the mouse wheel and scroll bar arrows. This works for me on Windows 7.