# How to write the Log Cat in android in a txt file but i don't want all the log, but only what is for my app

Tags: java, android, logcat

How to write the Log Cat in android in a txt file but i don't want all the log, but only what is for my app. i have this code but writes everything

```
 String fileName = "logcat.txt";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     System.out.println("CONTEXT : " + root);
     File outputFile = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
     System.out.println("FILE : " + outputFile);
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+ outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

how to make it to write only my app! the name of the app is nick.app

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter-spec parameter from logcat, more info there:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput

Example:

```
adb logcat -f /sdcard/logcat.txt MyApp:D *:S
```

This will display logs from MyApp tag with DEBUG minimum level (MyApp:D) and it will supress all the other logs (*:S).

Comment: This blog post may help- http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/android-log-logcat-to-file-while-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

maybe androlog (https://github.com/akquinet/androlog) could be an alternative? It's more versatile when it comes to logging and you can log to a file. Furthermore you can send reports about errors which is maybe what you are trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: no i don't want to take the errors! i have so much things that my app is doing so i need to write it somewhere to read it after because the log in eclipse is erasing the more

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can filter the Log cat output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044132/filter-tags-in-logcat-in-android-eclipse-plug-in

Comment: maybe you can run it through adb like so http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238