# Log Cat Running Continuously

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I am getting infinite number of lines in the log cat. Even if i am not running the program, the messages are getting displayed infinitely. I even reopened the eclipse.
But, I dont know, what is the reason. The memory in my C drive is 1.7 gb left. I hope this wont be a problem. Can you please tell me what the error could be.

This is the verbose logcat.

Log Cat Error :

```
DCD ON
 DCD ON
 DCD ON
 D/Tethering(373): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
 interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
 DCD ON
 DCD ON
E/AlarmManagerService(373): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 248683.937000000
V/AlarmManager(373): waitForAlarm result :8
V/AlarmManager(373): ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
 E/AlarmManagerService(373): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 248542.915000000
 W/AlarmManager(373): FACTORY_ON= 0
 D/STATUSBAR-Clock(492): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
 D/ClockWidget(373): refreshTime()
 TTS Message = It is 9 : 30 AM, Monday, February 24
 DCD ON
 D/BatteryService(373): update start
 level:100 scale:100 status:5 health:2 present:true voltage: 4313 temperature: 230 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17303181 invalid charger:0
02-24 09:30:04.331: D/ThermistorObserver(373): mBatteryBRForAMOLED : onReceive() : newTemperature : 230
updateLocked, mLastBroadcastState =0 , oldAction = null
 D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(492): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
onReceive() - level:100
 onReceive() - plugged:2
 D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(492): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_FULL:
 D/BatteryService(373): turn on LED for fully charged
 D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(492): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar(492): NORMAL_BATTERY
 D/PowerUI(492): getBatteryOnline : battery online file not found
 E/SMD(105): DCD ON
```

I took a some lines from log cat and displayed it.

I am not running alarm manager anywhere. I have not used it anywhere.

Comment: are you using Avd or real device.

Comment: while you are in debugging mode it's ok to have a live stream from device. You see all messages from all apps

Comment: It's totaly normal, logcat shows you all your device messages. You can set filters to see only your app related logs.

Comment: @nikis How should i remove myself from debugging mode then ?

Comment: @androidsanta Using Android.

Comment: @user3345483 see these are device OS logs and totally normal. you must have set an alarm in uyour phone so you get these logs. There are always some application (part of android OS ) that keep on running by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the logcat messages using this statement in the filter textbox:

```
tag:MyTag
```

or

```
app:com.myapplicationpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the logs because you have set alarm in your device and for all the other basic apps that your device has by default. :)

Answer (score 0):

Those logs are probably sent by the System..

Add a filter from the LogCat options so that you only see logs from a particular application or tag.. You can filter logs on the basis of type (i.e. error, warning, debug etc), Package name of your application, Tag of the log (the tag that you send in Log.d or Log.e etc) and even a regex.

Take a look at this answer for more details:
[Filter tags in LogCat (in Android Eclipse Plug-In)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044132/filter-tags-in-logcat-in-android-eclipse-plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are viewing the logs of a different emulator which has been deleted or no longer in use. You can check if it is the case and chose to press cancel on logcat for the avd device. It happened with me too but it was seeing logs of a deleted avd.